# I'm starting a Unity project however my coding environment has problems loading the project file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

The two most prominent error messages I get are these:

> Failed to load project file 'c:\Forest\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.

I'll also mention that I changed the omnisharp.path to the latest and have installed mono in futile hopes it might help

> c:\Users\myusername.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.13.omnisharp\1.37.14-beta.3.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1217,5):
> Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

I don't know if it's the core of my problem, but I tried to reinstall the developer package mentioned.

My operating system is Windows 10

Comment: Did this start occurring right after you create a new Unity project from the Unity Hub? Or did you make some change to your project that led to the errors? If you are unable to find what the issue is, you may just want to try uninstalling Visual Studios completely, then reinstall it.

Comment: Try opening the project in Visual Studio -- not Code. It will notice the error and tell you how you can fix it, e.g. if you need to download something and were downloading the wrong thing, it'll direct you to the proper page.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding in here for anyone else with a more common current issue that is very similar:

If you're using the new VS Code Extension for Unity that includes the C# dev kit, you will no longer need the 4.7.1 .Net Framework, just .NET 7 SDK or greater (most troubleshooting guides online do not cover this). Instead, you will need to make sure you have updated the Visual Studio Editor package to version 2.0.20 or greater within your Unity Editor.

This resolves the unsupported assembly project errors within VS Code and will enable intellisense for Unity specific C# methods. Included the screen capture below with the requirements provided by the extension itself.

[Unity Extension Requirements Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MntcH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alright i did open project in Visual Studio (not Code) and thn it told me that im using wrong version of .NET Framework Developer pack, after i downloaded the right one the problem is fixed so thank you all for answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a script on an object?